# Cannot render JavaScript from Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rjs

I want to display a modal window with an error message, when the user has entered something invalid in a form, but render another action if everything is OK. However, when I try to display the modal window with

```
render :js => "jQuery.facebox(#{...})"
```

only the actual JavaScript called is displayed:

```
try {
  jQuery.facebox(...)
} catch (e) { alert('RJS error:\n\n' + e.toString());
  alert('jQuery.facebox(\"<div class=\'error\'>Error</div>\")');
  throw e;
}
```

Comment: The question is: What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure you have a failsafe incase you user doesn't have javascript. otherwise they wouldn't know they were getting an error. As a personal rule i find that removing modal windows increases usability...doesn't really help the question, though thought i would share some words of wisdom.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried putting the code in a partial?  So instead of

```
render :js => "jQuery.facebox(#{...})"
```

try

```
render :partial => "my_facebox_popup"
```

Then inside of your **_my_facebox_popup.html.erb** partial put your code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
...
</script>
```

debug any errors you get with [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 render :update do|page|
   page <<  "jQuery.facebox(#{...})"
 end
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should specify in the jQuery call the dataType of the response you're waiting for.

E.g.:

```
$.ajax({ 
  url: "/controller/action/id", 
  success: function(){
    $(this).addClass("done");
  },
  dataType: 'script' 
});
```